# Cannot modify docnames of corpus when using get()

Tags: r, quanteda

I am trying to modify the `docnames` of a list of `corpus` objects through a for-loop. Usually, I use the function `get()` to access a given object while moving through the loop. It seems I cannot do this within the function `docnames()` of the package **quanteda**. I always get this error (conditional on your input object which in my case is `listofcorpora`):

```
Error in get(listofcorpora[i]) <- `*vtmp*` : 
  could not find function "get<-"
```

Please, find below a minimal with just two corpora. Originally, I have many more.

```r
library(quanteda)
#> Package version: 2.0.0
#> Parallel computing: 2 of 8 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'quanteda'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     View
library(stringr)

corp_2015_qtr1 <- corpus( c("The first document of the first corpus.",
                           "The second document of the first corpus" ) )
corp_2015_qtr2 <- corpus( c("The first document of the second corpus.",
                           "The second document of the second corpus" ) )

listofcorpora <- objects( pattern = "corp_\\d+" )

for ( i in seq_along( listofcorpora ) ) {
  current_year <- as.integer( str_extract( listofcorpora[ i ], "\\d+" ) )  current_qtr <- as.integer( str_extract( listofcorpora[ i ], "(?<=QTR)\\d" ) )
  current_docname <- str_c( current_year, 
                           "_qtr_", 
                           current_qtr, "_",
                           formatC( seq_len( ndoc( get( listofcorpora[ i ] ) ) ),
                                    width = 5, flag = "0" ) )
  docnames( get( listofcorpora[ i ] ) ) <- current_docname

}
#> Error in get(listofcorpora[i]) <- `*vtmp*`: could not find function "get<-"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The same error is raised whenever I use `docvars()` in the same fashion.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't create a list of corpera, instead of having x numbers of corpera in your environment? Then you can use lapply to do everything without having to use get.

Comment: @phiver Well, I am reading in the corpora from RData files. So everything stems from `list.files()`. This has been actually my way to go for a while now and has always been reliable. Could you please elaborate what you are suggesting?

Comment: Is each corpus in 1 RData file? Or are there more corpera in the RDate files? I'm assuming you load the data files with load?

Comment: Yes, a file called "corpus_2015_qtr1.RData" will contain a corpus object called the same way. And yes, each RData has only one single object in it. This allows me to have smaller objects in well structured and independent files.

Comment: The problem here is that `docnames() <-` does not seem to work with `get()`. You could ask the package authors to address this. But I think it would make more sense to adjust the way you work with these objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got the `RData` files from but generally it makes more sense to save objects via `saveRDS` and load them with `object <- readRDS` so you can control the object name or load the file directly into a list.

In your case I would turn your objects into a list via (as suggested by @phiver in the comments):

```
corpora_l <- lapply(listofcorpora, get)
names(corpora_l) <- listofcorpora
```

To get a cleaner environment you can now delete the superfluous objects:

```
# remove unnecessary objects
rm(list = c(listofcorpora, "listofcorpora"))
```

Working with this list seems easier in my opionion and more importantly: `docnames()` works with list objects:

```
for (i in seq_along(corpora_l)) {
  current_name <- names(corpora_l)[i]
  current_year <- as.integer( str_extract( current_name, "\\d+" ) )  
  current_qtr <- as.integer( str_extract( current_name, "(?<=qtr)\\d" ) )
  current_docname <- str_c( current_year, 
                            "_qtr_", 
                            current_qtr, "_",
                            formatC( seq_len( ndoc( corpora_l[[i]] ) ),
                                     width = 5, flag = "0" ) )
  docnames( corpora_l[[i]] ) <- current_docname
}
```

Also: I don't know what your plan is regarding the `docnames`, but it seems the year-qtr is more of a document variable. So you could change the last line in the loop to:

```
docvars(corpora_l[[i]], field = "quarter") <- str_c(current_year, 
                                                    "_qtr_", 
                                                    current_qtr)
```

Sorry I butchered your style there. I'm not used to the amount of spaces you leave in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think `docnames()` does not get along with `get()`. Indeed, what you suggested works pretty good. `RData` is just the usual file I am accustomed to..but I can change.